# Does a single rollback affect all transactions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction

When I run the following script:

```
begin transaction
    select XACT_STATE()

    select @@TRANCOUNT 

    begin transaction


    select XACT_STATE()

    select @@TRANCOUNT 

    begin transaction


    select XACT_STATE()

    select @@TRANCOUNT 

    rollback

    select XACT_STATE()

    select @@TRANCOUNT
```

I get the following result:

[image]

So one single rollback statement rolls back any number of transactions?

There is no point in writing the following then:

```
while @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      rollback
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be nested transactions? Have you read this Technet article? **[Nesting transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes commit and rollback behave differently in this respect.

Commit just decrements the `@@trancount`. Nothing is actually committed until that reaches zero.

Rollback will always rollback the transaction and set `@@trancount` to zero.

Just to be clear there is only one transaction going on, irrespective of the value of `@@trancount`. Nested transactions in SQL Server are a myth. See Paul Randal's blog post:

[A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real.](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)